# Tengo problemas tratando de instalar la libreria de ngx-paypal en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, paypal

tengo un problema instalando la libreria ngx-paypal y no estoy seguro si es un problema de incompatibilidades de versiones, me tira los siguientes errores cuando se intenta instalar la libreria pero no los entiendo muy bien, todavía no estoy en nivel de comprender este tipo de errores y quería saber si algún compañero con más experiencia me podría ayudar. Son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la versión 11 de Angular para este proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda

Comment: Prueba ejecutar `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` y coméntame  si resuelve el problema.

Comment: No, no me funciono Jaime, me sale el mismo error y al importar la librería en app.module me sale que:  "No se encuentra el módulo "ngx-paypal" ni sus declaraciones de tipos correspondientes."

Comment: ¿Ya ejecutaste `npm install ngx-paypal --save`? ¿Por qué no veo `ngx-paypal` en tus dependencias? Si sigue sin funcionar checa los comandos de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66990138/8838721). Si no te funcionan, borra el `node_modules ` y el  `package-lock.json` y ejecuta nuevamente `npm install`. Me haces saber qué te funcionó.

Comment: Brother, muchisimas gracias de verdad. Me funciono ejecutando los dos comandos que están en ese enlace que diste . Estos dos: "npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps", "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true". Pero sabes que hacen estos comandos o cual era el error que me estaba dando? siempre es bueno conocer porque suceden estás cosas

Comment: Normalmente las librerías que usas tienen dependencias. Esas dependencias se conocen como dependencias de pares. La librería `ngx-paypal` tiene dependencia con `angular 13`, pero tu estás usando `angular 11`. Lo que hace ese comando es de cierto modo `forzar` que la librería use la versión de la dependencia que tú estás usando y no se instale la que ella declara... Que por cierto, si tu proyecto aún está en desarrollo, deberías considerar actualizar a Angular 13. Vas dos versiones atrás.

Comment: Hola ya entiendo Jaime con razón ahora cuando ejecuto el proyecto me sale varios errores como si necesitará instalar angular 13 para poder usar esta librería de Paypal y por acá estoy sufriendo pasando el proyecto primero de la versión 11 a la 12 :´(

Comment: No debe ser muy problemático usando las indicaciones de  https://update.angular.io/ para las versiones correspodientes.

Comment: @Hugo si puedes agrega una propia respuesta a tu pregunta y márcala como solucionada y así le sirva a alguien en el futuro.